# How to make a condition LIKE to check the file name Picked in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I'm trying to restore `.db` file type. Since the `FilePickerResult` does not support `.db` extension I got forced to use `type: FileType.any` and then tried to check the file picked if it has some thing like `['*.db']` or `['%.db']` but it won't work and the condition does not be a true, my code:

```
                onTap: () async {
                  var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
                  var dbPath = join(databasesPath, 'ledger.db');
                  print('dbPath $dbPath');
                  FilePickerResult? result =
                      await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                    type: FileType.any,
                    //type: FileType.custom,
                    //allowedExtensions: ['db'],
                  );
                  print('result ${result?.names}');
                  if (result != null && result.names == ['*.db']) {
                    File source = File(result.files.single.path!);
                    await source.copy(dbPath);
                    print('Successfully Restored DB');
                  } else {
                    print('Some Error XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
                  }
                },
```

So I need some thing as `Like` in `SQL` to check the name like `fileName.db` but in flutter with using `if (result != null && result.names like ['%.db'])`.

NOTE: this method works fine without any condition, but I'm afraid that the user can picked any file which not db file so the database will get a crash.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

== checks for equality without considering any Regex characters. You can use [endsWith](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/endsWith.html) instead:

```
result.names.length == 1 && result.names[0].endsWith('.db')
```

If you want to use Regex

```
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'.db');
if (result != null && result.names.length == 1 && exp.hasMatch(result.names[0]))
```

Note that an extension does not guarantee the contents of the file.